# React+gsap use random animation element group can't work when it complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web-frontend, gsap

I use `gsap` to create the animation.

When the button is clicked creates a bubble animation.

When animation is completed destroys itself.

I think the question is use map at `React component` but I can't find another case

Here is my React code and js fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xiaowang/ueqsg83j/58/

```
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin)

const Bubble = ({ onClose, data }) => {
    const pointRef = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
    const path = []
    let offsetY = 0
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const y = offsetY - Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 30)
      offsetY = y
      path.push({ x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 - 20), y })
    }
    gsap.to(pointRef.current, 5, {
      motionPath: {
        path,
        type: 'cubic'
      },
      onComplete: () => onClose()
    })
    return () => {}
  }, [])
    return (<span className="bubble" ref={pointRef}>{data.id}</span>)
}

const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [bubbles, setBubbles] = useState([])

    const handleCreate = () => {
    setBubbles([...bubbles, {id: count}])
    setCount(count + 1)
  }

  const handleClose = index => {
    const newBubbles = [...bubbles]
    newBubbles.splice(index, 1)
    setBubbles(newBubbles)
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrap">
      {
        bubbles.map((item, index) => (
            <Bubble
            key={item.id}
            data={item}
            onClose={() => handleClose(index)} />
        ))
      }
      <button type="button" onClick={handleCreate}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Depending on how many bubbles you'll need, it might make more sense to create a bunch of bubbles at the beginning (100 or however many) and then animate specific ones when the button is clicked. Creating and destroying elements and changing the size of arrays over and over again is not very performant. I'm betting doing so would work around the issue that you're facing as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure it will help much, but I've moved your code to the sandbox, because I couldn't find the console on jsfiddle, and made small modification to the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-gsap-issue-7tkrd

Main changes are.

Change handleClose implementation to a simple filter:

```
const handleClose = id => () => {
    setBubbles(prev => prev.filter(bubble => bubble.id !== id));
  };
```

Changed how we invoke it (and render in general):

```
return (
    <div className="wrap">
      {bubbles.map(item => (
        <Bubble key={item.id} data={item} onClose={handleClose(item.id)} />
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={handleCreate}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

It has fixed the issue, if I understood your problem correctly, and I think that problem was in how you have used splice. Hope that will help.